# What should I do so that my result is not lowercase?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

How can I make sure that in the place of man and wife there is their code, for example, husband = M and wife = F
i tried to do it through if and if-else but i have to use in div and when i use div my result becomes lowercase

My code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    Фамилия: <input type="text" v-model="surname"><br>
    Имя: <input type="text" v-model="name"><br>
    Дата рождение: <input type="text" v-model="birthday"><br>

    <input type="radio" value="Мужчина" v-model="sex">
    <label>Мужчина</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" value="Женшина" v-model="sex">
    <label>Женшина</label><br>

    Гражданства: <input type="text" v-model="citizenship"><br>
    Серия пасспорт: <input type="text" v-model="passportSeries"><br>
    Срок пасспорт: <input type="text" v-model="passportExpirationDate"><br><br>

    -{{ surname }} {{ name }} {{ birthday }}+{{ sex }}/{{ citizenship }}/нп{{ passportSeries }}/{{ passportExpirationDate }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data (){
    return {
      surname: '',
      name: '',
      birthday: '',
      sex: '',
      citizenship: '',
      passportSeries: '',
      passportExpirationDate: '',
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

My Result:

[image]

After using if and div

```
  <div>
    Фамилия: <input type="text" v-model="surname"><br>
    Имя: <input type="text" v-model="name"><br>
    Дата рождение: <input type="text" v-model="birthday"><br>

    <input type="radio" value="Мужчина" v-model="sex" >
    <label>Мужчина</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" value="Женшина" v-model="sex">
    <label>Женшина</label><br>

    Гражданства: <input type="text" v-model="citizenship"><br>
    Серия пасспорт: <input type="text" v-model="passportSeries"><br>
    Срок пасспорт: <input type="text" v-model="passportExpirationDate"><br><br>

    -{{ surname }} {{ name }} {{ birthday }}+<div v-if="sex == 'Мужчина'">М</div><div v-else-if="sex == 'Женшина'">Ж</div>/{{ citizenship }}/нп{{ passportSeries }}/{{ passportExpirationDate }}
  </div>
```

[image]

How can I do it in one line and with gender codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is to use a computed value.
You can do something like this :

```
computed: {
    genderLabel() {
        return this.sex == 'Мужчина' ? 'M' : 'F';
    }
}
```

and then in the template replace 'sex' with 'genderLabel' :

`{{ surname }} {{ name }} {{ birthday }}+{{ genderLabel }}...`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this in your radio v-bind:value="'M'" and v-bind:value="'F'"

ex. `<input type="radio" v-model="sex" v-bind:value="'M'">`

after that you can use the line you had like this

```
{{ surname }} {{ name }} {{ birthday }}+{{ sex }}/{{ citizenship }}/нп{{ passportSeries }}/{{ passportExpirationDate }}
```

Comment: after adding v-bind:value=" 'M' " I get an error
[vue/no-duplicate-attributes]
Duplicate attribute 'value'.

Comment: You have to remove the first value and only keep the v-bind:value

Comment: Just edited my answer, my fault, if this worked please mark it as answer